# Prefix with no unit with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

How can I typeset a number with a prefix but without a unit with siunitx?  The following code

```
\SI{1.0}{\mega}
```

gives this error: "Prefix with no unit."

Comment: Of course it does: you can't have 'one mega', only 'one mega `<something>`'. What is the aim here?

Comment: I have a table with a column called "number of nodes", and I would like to write "1M" in one of the cells.

Comment: @jalalhugo That's 1×10⁶

Comment: Or `\num{1e6}` using `siunitx`.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Of course!

Comment: Or just 1e6 using the S column option of siunitx

Comment: I understand that "1M" goes against the standard, but ultimately I think that the notation should be at the discretion of the user, so in my opinion raising an error (as opposed to a warning) is pushing it.

Comment: @jalalhugo I agree. It should be only a warning. I'm also using it when discussing unity conversion to teach a trick to convert a number from `\meter\squared` to `\deca\meter\squared`: `\meter\squared = \frac{\da\squared\meter\squared}{\da\squared} = \frac{\deca\meter\squared}{100}`.

Answer (score 24):

You can of course do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\nothing}{\relax}

\begin{document}
\SI{1.0}{\mega\nothing} is a wrong way to typeset data.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you should think at least twice whether this is a good way to express yourself and your readers will understand what you mean. With

```
\num{1e6}
```

the printout would be much clearer and not so wider.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable way to express oneself in some fields.